# Change how information is shown in list box from textfile?

Tags: vb.net, listbox, text-files

Is there a way to change how information is displayed in the list box from a text file? I want to show the names from the text file as first name and then last name and still keep it alphabetized by last name. Right now it is displayed in the list box as last name, first name. Names in the text file are formatted "Langley Judy,321-1111"

```
Public Class frmMembership
    ' Read all lines from text file
    Dim file() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("MemberPhones.txt")

    Private Sub ModifyToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    End Sub
    Private Sub frmMembership_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Display()
    End Sub
    ' Displays users from text file and sorts by last name 
    Public Sub Display()
        lstDisplay.Items.Clear()
        For Each n In file
            lstDisplay.Items.Add(n.ToString.Split(",")(0))

        Next
        lstDisplay.Sorted = True

        txtName.Text = ""
        txtPhone.Text = ""
    End Sub
    ' Closes program and writes new lines to text file
    Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Me.Close()
        IO.File.WriteAllLines("MemberPhones.txt", file)
    End Sub
    ' Query to display users phone number and name when selected in output textboxes
    Private Sub lstDisplay_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstDisplay.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim query = From p In file
                    Let name As String = p.ToString.Split(",")(0)
                    Let phone = p.ToString.Split(",")(1)
                    Where name = lstDisplay.SelectedItem
                    Select name, phone

        txtName.Text = query.ToList.First.name.ToString
        txtPhone.Text = query.ToList.First.phone.ToString
    End Sub

    Private Sub ModifyToolStripMenuItem_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ModifyToolStripMenuItem.Click
        If lstDisplay.Text <> "" Then
            ' Matches array element with name from text file 
            For i As Integer = 0 To file.Count - 1
                If (file(i).Split(",")(0)) = lstDisplay.Text Then
                    file(i) = txtName.Text + "," + txtPhone.Text
                End If
            Next
            Display()
        Else
            MsgBox("Please add information")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddToolStripMenuItem.Click
        If (txtName.Text <> "") And (txtPhone.Text <> "") Then
            ReDim Preserve file(file.Count) 'Adds one more index to the array
            file(file.Count - 1) = txtName.Text + "," + txtPhone.Text
            Display()
        Else
            MsgBox("Please add information")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub DeleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DeleteToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Dim deleteName As String = lstDisplay.SelectedItem

        'Deleting data and now it will hold one less
        Dim tempName(lstDisplay.Items.Count - 2) As String

        If deleteName <> "" Then
            'User will select name to delete here
            Dim query = From n In file
                        Let name As String = n.Split(",")(0)
                        Where name <> deleteName
                        Select n

            'New data will be written into the text file
            ReDim file(tempName.Count - 1)
            file = query.ToArray
            Display()
        Else
            MsgBox("Nothing data to delete")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

My text file looks like this (`FirstName` and `LastName` separated by a comma):

```
Mary,Smith,555-1212
John,Jones,333-1212
George,Washington,713-2212
Peter,Pan,313-3435
```

The class would look like this:

```
Public Class MemberPhone
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
    Public Property Phone As String
    'Allows you to create a new MemberPhone without having to set properties individually
    Public Sub New(fName As String, lName As String, Number As String)
        FirstName = fName
        LastName = lName
        Phone = Number
    End Sub
    'This is called by the ListBox for what to display
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{FirstName} {LastName} - {Phone}"
    End Function
End Class
```

And in the Form:

```
Private PhoneList As New List(Of MemberPhone)

Private Sub FillPhoneList()
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("MemberPhones.txt")
    For Each line In lines
        Dim splits = line.Split(","c)
        PhoneList.Add(New MemberPhone(splits(0), splits(1), splits(2)))
    Next
    'This orders the PhoneList by LastName
    PhoneList = (From mp In PhoneList
                 Order By mp.LastName).ToList
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    FillPhoneList()
    'Binds the ListBox to the ordered PhoneList
    ListBox1.DataSource = PhoneList
End Sub
```

The entire object is inserted in each item in the Listbox. All the properties of that object are available.

```
Private Sub lstDisplay_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    txtName.Text = DirectCast(ListBox1.SelectedItem, MemberPhone).FirstName
    txtPhone.Text = DirectCast(ListBox1.SelectedItem, MemberPhone).Phone
End Sub
```

I changed a few of the control names to match my test project so I wouldn't have so many red squiggles.